# Sylius: Change design of Sylius front end

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I am new to Symfony as well as Sylius. Can anyone guide me how can I change design of Sylius front end. I want to use the Kuteshop template in it?

I want to change the front end UI of the Sylius project.

What I did is:
I copied my css, js, images etc files in web directory in a separate folder with name template (template/asstes/css/, template/assets/js/ and so on). Then I created a folder app/resources/SyliusWebBundle/Views/frontend/Homepage and also I created a file app/resources/SyliusWebBundle/Views/frontend/layout.html.twig. I defined the assets and other components but no result.

My template assets was not showing up, also I was not getting any information in it.

Does it help to get some solution to me?

Thanks so much.

Comment: make sure the folder `Frontend` has an uppercase `F`, clear cache and try again. Did that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path must be app/Resources/SyliusWebBundle/**views**/**Frontend**/Homepage

Comment: If my design support a different layout, then should I override whole sylius bundle?

Comment: You can override app/Resources/SyliusWebBundle/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig in order to modify the layout

Comment: Thanks so much, Can you guide more about it?

Comment: All views from the frontend extends this file. 
The easy way is to copy Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig into app/Resources/SyliusWebBundle/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig and do all the modification you want.
If you use the last version of Sylius you can create a theme but i don't know if it is 100% fonctionnal and if the structure might change

Comment: Do I need to run the assets:install after that?

Comment: If you add assets yes, you must also run cache:clear

Comment: Thanks so much, It was the thing I wanted